# is there an equivalent to the dkms tool in raspbian buster?

Tags: wifi, pi-2, kernel

I am installing a wifi dongle on an RP2B and the only instructions I can find were for Linux Mint using:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
```

I get a command not found. How is this done in Raspian?

Answer (score 1):

> Automatically installing Linux kernel modules with the DKMS framework
>   is a convenient way of distributing drivers that are maintained
>   outside of the official kernel. However, while DKMS is included in
>   many popular Linux distributions and supports most kernel modules, it
>   can’t always guarantee the proper installation of a third-party
>   module. *[Source](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/596-pros-and-cons-dkms)*

It's a command like `make` to install/add/change some kernel modules or drivers. However, if you concerned to install a driver by `dkms` you should install its packages.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

After that, you can install a related driver by the `dkms`. Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=175886) to find more about it.

---

***References:***

- [Raspberry pi machine type and dkms](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=175886)
- [Pros and Cons of Using DKMS](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/596-pros-and-cons-dkms)
- [Dynamic Kernel Module Support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support)

Answer (score 1):

For the future, you can get hints about missing commands directly in the command line:

```
$ sudo apt install command-not-found
$ sudo update-command-not-found
$ dkms
The program 'dkms' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Of course it's not smart enough to tell you that `dkms` is indeed the command you need, or whether it's actually working on Raspbian, but it will take you one step further.